# Shortcut for Incremental SELECTION in eclipse (NOT incremental SEARCH)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Is there an eclipse shortcut which selects scopes in incremental manner.
IntellijIdea does this by CMD+W.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scope selection:

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Up Arrow</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Down Arrow</kbd>

**My default key configuration:
OS: Ubuntu 14.04 Eclipse: Luna**

[image]

Comment: I already tried that. But mac seems not to have this. I tried to get in key bindings also. But found nothing useful with search terms "scope" or "selection". If that is working in your machine, please tell me key binding name.

Comment: Scope selection:<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Page UP</kbd>. This is by default mac key binding. Thanks a lot